# The PHP uploade code not working in online webserver

Tags: php

This code working fine in localhost but working in online webserver
whenever I try to upload the files using online hosting, this code does not work for me:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name      = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if (isset($name)) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $location = 'images/';
            if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location . $name)) {
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="save.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check server logs.

Comment: And check permissions on $location.

Comment: check images folder is writable, obligatory note your code is insecure and allows php scripts to be uploaded

Comment: Getting really tired of these “worked on localhost, but not on server”-type of “questions” … Do some basic _debugging_ then! Anyone who wrote code like this with a modicum amount of purpose, should be aware in which places this _could_ potentially fail - and therefor also know, what needs to be checked.

Comment: Check your PHP’s file_uploads configuration.

Comment: In your PHP.ini configuration file, you will find a directive called file_uploads. This directive specifies whether PHP should allow HTTP uploads or not. In default PHP installations, this is given the value “1”, which is BOOLEAN for TRUE – meaning file uploads are allowed by default. However, if your web host has disabled file uploads, then you may find that this directive has been set to “0”. To check the value of this directive, you can simply check your PHP.ini file.

Comment: thanks to all the code is now working finally for me